# Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "" on Win32_TerminalServiceSetting

Tags: powershell, terminal-services

I have created a Powershell function to enable or disable session logons remotely on a server. It is basically the Powershell equivalent of "change logon /enable".

It works on most machines, but for some reason I don't understand, for some it returns the following error :

```
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "" ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
                           at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
                           at System.Management.ManagementObject.Put(PutOptions options)
                           at System.Management.ManagementObject.Put()
                           at Put(Object , Object[] )
                           at System.Management.Automation.MethodInformation.Invoke(Object target, Object[] arguments)
                           at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] 
                        originalArguments)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] 
                        originalArguments)
                           at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.MethodInvokeDotNet(String methodName, Object target, MethodInformation[] methodInformation, 
                        PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments)
                           at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.MethodInvoke(PSMethod method, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.BaseMethodInvoke(PSMethod method, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments)
                           at System.Management.Automation.PSMethod.Invoke(PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments)
                           at System.Management.Automation.PSMethod.Invoke(Object[] arguments)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Language.PSInvokeMemberBinder.InvokeAdaptedMember(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args)
                           at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

The error stack trace doesn't help me.

I'm running the same code with the same local admin user on all machines.

Here is the actual code snippet :

```
$TSConnector = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TerminalServiceSetting -Namespace "root/cimv2/terminalservices" -Authentication PacketPrivacy
$TSConnector.Logons = 0
$TSConnector.Put()
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on several Server 2012R2-2016 hosts, please share a bit more detail about the failing host. Maybe it wasn't enabled for terminal services in the first place or the service is stopped?

Comment: You may be onto something @GrigorySergeev. All servers are running 2008R2 but I've noticed that their Remote Desktop Session Host configuration is slightly different : those that work fine have Citrix ICA 3.0 on them whereas the failing servers only have RDP 7.1.

Comment: well none of my test subjects have ICA, yet working fine. Windows updates need a follow up reboot?..

Comment: You were right : the failing servers do not have the RD Session Host role installed, and, as a result, are configured for "Remote Desktop for Administration". I found an article on Technet listing the limitations of this mode : 

The following are limitations of Remote Desktop for Administration:  
- The default connection (RDP-Tcp) only allows a maximum of two simultaneous remote connections.  
- Licensing settings cannot be configured.  
- RD Connection Broker settings cannot be configured.  
- User logon mode cannot be configured.

Comment: See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770759(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: The thing is, none of my test subjects had RD roles installed. MS have changed Remote Desktop services after 2008R2 release substantially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that, on Windows Server 2008R2, if the Remote Desktop Session Host role is not installed, the server is configured for "Remote Desktop for Administration".

As explained on [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770759(v=ws.11).aspx) :

> The following are limitations of Remote Desktop for Administration:
>
> 1. The default connection (RDP-Tcp) only allows a maximum of two simultaneous remote connections.
> 2. Licensing settings cannot be configured.
> 3. RD Connection Broker settings cannot be configured.
> 4. **User logon mode cannot be configured.**

So in the end I had to catch that exception and revert back to using `change logon /disable` in that particular case.

Kudos to @GrigorySergeev for pointing me in the right direction!